# Breaking a long Hash into separate lines with Groovy

Tags: string, hash, groovy

I have a long hash with no spaces (64+ characters) and I need to display 2 of these per row or a table.  To keep the table a respectable width, I want to break these hashes into multiple lines.

I'm looking for some cool Groovy recipe for doing this or some sort of HTML style that might take care of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show 8 chars per line, you could do:

```
hash.toList().collate( 8 )*.join().join( '\n' )
```

Comment: thanks.  That's adding spaces between each group of 8.  I'd rather not have the spaces.  But this is 99% of what I need.

Comment: You know what?  That's not what's happening.  I need to do br instead of \n.

Comment: Or, you could try a `&shy;` if you want to [tell the browser where breaks can occur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen)